# Use different pandas version for different tasks in the same DAG (Airflow)

Tags: virtualenv, airflow

Say I have two tasks which uses two versions of, say, pandas

```py
#my_task_one
import pandas as pd  #Pandas 1.0.0
def f1(data):
    .
    .
    return 0
```

and

```py
#my_task_two
import pandas as pd   #version 2.0.0
def f2(data):
    .
    .
    return 0
```

In my airflow (local, no Docker), is there a way to create a venv or requirement-file for each task e.g

```py
#dag.py
t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "t1",
        python_callable = f1,
        requirements = "my_task_one_requirement.txt"  #How to set requirements for this task?
    )

t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "t2",
        python_callable = f2,
        requirements = "my_task_two_requirement.txt"   #How to set requirements for this task?
    )

t1>>t2
```

In case it can't be in the same DAG-file, is there a way to specify the requirements for a given DAG-file e.g placing `t1` and `t2` in `DAG1` and `DAG2` respectively, but with different packages/requirement-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow has [PythonVirtualenvOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonvirtualenvoperator) that is suitable for this use case.

```
t1 = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="t1",
    python_callable=f1,
    requirements=["pandas==1.0.0"],
)

t2 = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="t2",
    python_callable=f2,
    requirements=["pandas==2.0.0"],
)
```

Comment: Do you know, if you can parse where to download the package from? E.g `pyTorch` downloads it from `https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`